# SQL return if set matches

Tags: sql

I normally know how to ask detailed questions but this is difficult for me to describe.

It's a very simple concept, but I don't know what to call it.

Lets say the user puts has 'materials' "A, B, C, D". I want to return all 'projects' that can be made with those materials. Let's say I have projects 1, 2, 3, and 4 that require [A, C], [D, F, G], [A,B,C,R,Q], and [A,C,D] respectively. I want to return 1 and 4 because those can be made whereas 2 and 3 cannot so they should not be returned.

Is that clear? I'm not sure what to call it. Also, any recommendations on table setup? It's easy for me to have a project table and project requirements table with a 1-many relationship.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag correctly.  Also, show sample data.

Comment: I prefer MySQL because it's cheaper to run but I could run T-SQL if I have to. I know MySQL is more limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to turn the condition around. If you're looking for all projects that can be made with only the materials on hand, this means you are looking for all projects except those that require materials you do not have. This can be expressed with *NOT EXISTS* rather easily.

Assuming for a minute you have two tables `Projects` and `ProjectMaterials`, a query could look something like:

```
select *
from Projects p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from ProjectMaterials pm
    where pm.ProjectId = p.Id
    and pm.MaterialId not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
)
```

This query should be relatively SQL-flavor-agnostic, but of course change it as necessary for your particular variant.

Regarding table design, I would recommend a table for projects and a table for materials, joined many-to-many.

I've created a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a78e/1) of this query and structure using your sample data above.

Comment: I like this answer, it seems really solid. Now, (and this is not a requirement) what if I needed certain quantities? Would that easily do that? Do I just make it so the project materials are n long ( project 1 needs A, A, A, B) or would I have a quantity column?

Comment: I would use a quantity column, but if you are then dealing with quantity on hand this whole query becomes a different problem. I think you can still use a similar approach, but would have to check each material quantity as well as checking for other materials.

Comment: Thank you! The reason why it's not a requirement is because most projects require only 1 and I can always sort it out in the front end too. Also, If I did sort it out in the front end, I could show 2 sets where you have enough materials, and you almost have enough.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to assume that you had a table called `ProjectMaterials` (as @lc. does), then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select pm.projectid
from ProjectMaterials pm
group by pm.projectid
having sum(case when pm.materialid not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `product`, `status`) VALUES
  (1,'A',1),
  (2,'B',1),
  (3,'C',1),
  (4,'D',1),
  (5,'E',0),
  (6,'F',0),
  (7,'G',0),
  (8,'R',0);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `project` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `projects` (`id`, `project`) VALUES
  (1,'1'),
  (2,'2'),
  (3,'3'),
  (4,'4');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects_products` (
  `project_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int unsigned NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `projects_products` (`project_id`, `product_id`) VALUES
  (1,1),
  (1,3),
  (2,2),
  (2,6),
  (2,7),
  (3,1),
  (3,2),
  (3,3),
  (3,8),
  (3,9),
  (4,1),
  (4,3),
  (4,4);


select * from project where id not in (
select distinct b.id from projects_products a join projects b
on a.project_id = b.id
left join products c
on a.product_id = c.id
where c.status <> 1)
```